# JavaScript AmCharts "TypeError: r.axes[t.valueAxis.id] is undefined"

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm trying to create a chart with AmChart, and I need two diferent axis for two graphs in the same chart. I created to variables:

```
var captchaAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
var searchAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
```

Then I am trying to set the positions:

```
captchaAxis.position = "right";
searchAxis.position = "left";
```

And then added them to my graph:

```
captchaGraph.valueAxis = "captchaAxis";
searchGraph.valueAxis = "searchAxis";
```

If I run this code I only get the error message "TypeError: r.axes[t.valueAxis.id] is undefined" spammed into the console.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph's [`valueAxis`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#valueAxis) property needs to either point to an id that you set in the valueAxis variables you created (i.e. `captchaAxis.id = "captchaAxis"; captchaGraph.valueAxis = "captchaAxis";`), or the valueAxis variables themselves. Since your code doesn't show an id being set on your axis variables, set the graph's valueAxis properties to the variables without the quotes:

```
captchaGraph.valueAxis = captchaAxis;
searchGraph.valueAxis = searchAxis;
```